# Как считать ч\б изображение только с 2 цветами(ч\б) и преобразовать его в массив из 0 и единиц?

Tags: python, изображения, графика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,0,0]
[0,1,1,1,0]
[0,0,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Примите размеры одного черного лепестка (у креста) за шаги (соответсвенно, ширина - шаг по Х,  высота - по Y) и шагайте по картинке.  Каждый шаг проверяйте на черный, или белый, ну, допустим в середине - если там черная точка, то 1, иначе 0.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как это реализовать в программе)

Comment: Какие размеры у картинки, разрешение?  И у лепестка креста?

Comment: 2000-800. хочу сделать платформер с графикой на пайгейме

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте условную рамку для шага с размерами равными размеру лепестка креста (на картинке красный прямоугольник на лепестке - это для наглядности выбора размеров рамки) и дальше начните шагать по изображению (красные прямоугольнки), проверяя значения в середине каждого шага (красная точка): белое - 0, черное (лучше, не белое) - 1.

Таким образом вы и заполните свою матрицу (Код приблизительный):

```
width  = # ширина всей картинки
height = # высота всей картинки

stepX = # ширина лепестка
stepY = # высота лепестка

cols = width / stepX   # Количество столбцов в матрице
rows = height / stepY  # Количество строк в матрице

# Индексы столбцов и строк
r = 0
c = 0

# Создаем матрицу и инициализируем ее значения -1
matrix = [[-1 for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows)]

for r in range(rows):
  for c in range(cols):    
    # получаем координаты центра текущего прямоугольника
    px = c*stepX + stepX /2   # или stepX*(c + 1.0/2)
    py = r*stepY + stepY /2   # или stepY*(r + 1.0/2)

    #Берем значение цвета из картинки по текущим координатам px, py
    color = <картинка>.getPixelColorBy(px, py)

    # Устанавливаем значение в матрицу
    matrix[r][c] = 1 if color != white else 0 # color != white? 1: 0
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как по нему шагать то? можешь пример кода отправить пожалуйста?

Comment: @LeonidTheGod добавил условный код, дальше сами.